# ArrowJS state updates are not reflected in the template

Tags: javascript, arrowjs

I am trying to build a chrome extension using arrowjs,
One of my components has state which looks like this:

```js
const state = reactive({
  loading: false,
  current_note: null,
});
```

I am using the loading property from the state to conditionally renders a loading indicator using another Arrowjs component:

```js
${() =>
  state.loading &&
    html`
      <div class="ctnn-loading-placeholder ctnn-mb-1_5">
        ${LoadingIcon({ width: 35, height: 35, color: "hsl(0, 0%, 50%)" })}
      </div>
    `
}
```

This is how i update the state:

```js
async function findOneNote(selected) {
  try {
    state.loading = true;

    const note = await fetchFindOneNote();

    state.current_note = { ...note };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Couldn't fetch note", error);
  } finally {
    state.loading = false;
  }
}
```

Using $on method, i can see that the state is indeed updated:

```js
state.$on("loading", () => console.log("loading", state.loading));
state.$on("current_note", () => console.log("current_note", state.current_note));
```

However, the dom is not updating at all, i have other components that implement this pattern, but this is the only one which doesn't work.

Example:

```js
${() => modalState.menu === MODAL_MENUS.CREATE_NOTE && NoteForm(createNote)}
```

Here is how the full component looks like:

```js
export function NotesList() {
  const state = reactive({
    loading: false,
    current_note: null,
  });
  
  // Function declarations...
  // Function declarations...

  return html`
    <div id="ctnn-form-container">
      <form action="" @submit="${submitNoteParameters}">
        <div class="ctnn-form-control ctnn-mb-1_5">
          ${SuggestedInput()}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    ${() =>
      state.loading &&
      html`
        <div class="ctnn-loading-placeholder ctnn-mb-1_5">
          ${LoadingIcon({ width: 35, height: 35, color: "hsl(0, 0%, 50%)" })}
        </div>
      `}
  `;
}
```

I also have tried wrapping the function expression inside a div, but no difference.

My questions are:

1. Is there any special conditions that cause the template to ignore updates in the state ?
2. Am i using the nested html function correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the part of the component where this is used: ```js
${() =>
  state.loading &&
    html`
      <div class="ctnn-loading-placeholder ctnn-mb-1_5">
        ${LoadingIcon({ width: 35, height: 35, color: "hsl(0, 0%, 50%)" })}
      </div>
    `
}
```

Comment: @jpschroeder sure, i have edited the question to include it.

Comment: @jpschroeder another thing that i found is, when i update the state from setTimeout or setInterval, the dom reacts to the changes.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? alpha-8?

Comment: @jpschroeder i am using this version, ^1.0.0-alpha.8

Comment: I dont immediately see anything wrong, but it could be in the nuance of the implementation too. Happy to keep looking at it, but maybe try posting a reproduction in codepen and I can iterate on it there.

Comment: @jpschroeder Hi, this is the simplified version codepen https://codepen.io/salmanrf/pen/gOdKEEo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not specifically related to ArrowJS. In your example, there is a typo `setTimeOut` which is not valid since JavaScript is case sensitive. Since it is in a try/catch block with a squelched "catch" section (so you don’t notice the error) — followed by a `finally` block that sets `state.loading` back to false, the sequence is:

```
state.loading = true
error, promise rejected immediately
state.loading = false
```

Here’s an example with `setTimeOut` adjusted to `setTimeout`:

https://codepen.io/justin-schroeder/pen/MWqBQzO

Comment: oops, sorry for the typo, but i believe that is not the problem, since there isn't any such typo in the real code. Unfortunately i haven't been able to replicate the problem on codepen, but i can show you the file, https://github.com/salmanrf/catatann-extension/blob/main/lib/content-scripts/components/NoteList.js#L31-L58.